# Can i avoid this error. E/InputMethodManager: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected .flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView

Tags: flutter, latex, flutter-dependencies, flutter-release

I'm Using the `flutter_tex` library
[flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex)

```
  flutter_tex: ^3.6.7+10
```

I want to release the app in the play store. My app is running fine. But I'm getting this message in the Debug Console.
**Can I Avoid It?**

---

```
TeXView(
  renderingEngine: const TeXViewRenderingEngine.katex(),
  child: TeXViewDocument('\$\$$text\$\$'),
),
```

---

### Getting this error:

`E/InputMethodManager(28630): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=137 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{86b4162 VFEDHVC.. ........ 0,0-864,188}`

```
E/InputMethodManager(28630): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=137 
actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{86b4162 VFEDHVC.. 
........ 0,0-864,188}
D/EGL_emulation(28630): eglMakeCurrent: 0x963e0360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xebe0dce0)
E/InputMethodManager(28630): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=138 
actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{47b28d1 VFEDHVC.. 
........ 0,0-864,188}
D/HostConnection(28630): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x6bd973d0, tid 28933
D/HostConnection(28630): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1        
ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 
ANDROID_EMU_vulkan     ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings 
ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache 
ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync 
ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit 
GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing 
ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
E/InputMethodManager(28630): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=139 
actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{d55bd6b VFEDHVC.. 
........ 0,0-864,188}
E/InputMethodManager(28630): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=140 
actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{24c90e0 VFEDHVC.. 
........ 0,0-864,188}
```

Is this safe to not care about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to clicking on this widget and will not be fixed by resetting or deleting the build files.
All you have to do is design an operation that clicks on this widget or add a read-only feature to it, and this will solve the problem.
Your day without bugs!

Answer (score 1):

We have to enable hybrid composition, set WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
You can look at this github link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40716#issuecomment-708076795. This helped me solve this error.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. A clean rebuild of the project fixed it.

Comment: This problem is due to clicking on this widget and will not be fixed by resetting or deleting the build files.